# Fetch float values from table using range (1 to 6) in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Let's consider a table,

```
Col1
1.1
2.1
8.1
5.7
3.4
5.6
9.2
8.3
```

from above table, I want to retrieve the values from range 1 to 6 as

```
Col1
1.1
2.1
5.7
3.4
5.6
```

How would I get this using range (1 to 6) in SQL?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: What options have you considered and tried?

Comment: You would use a where clause with two predicates. > 1 and < 6

Comment: @jarlh I am using MySQL ..

Comment: @DaleK ... I did not try this earlier, but when I tried using the method by SeanLange .....I got the desired result. Actually I was thinking it might have some tricky syntax or something else but this served the purpose... Thanks a lot all.......